# How to inner join two tables based on relationship defined in two other tables

Tags: mysql

I have five tables :
1)Employee table
2)Employee_Department table
2)Type table
3)Code table
4)Code Type table

Now in Type table I have col as follows:

```
Id  Employee_Department_Id  Code
1       1                    1
2       1                    2
```

In Table Employee have normal employee info such as :

```
Id  Employee_name  Employee_Salary
1    empName        20000
```

In Table Employee_Department I have:

```
Id    Emp_Id  Department_id 
1     1        1
```

In Table Code I have :

```
Id   Code_Type_Id
1      1
2      1
```

In Table CodeType I have:

```
Id    Code_Type_name
1     Abc
2     Cde
```

My main objective is to get User's Code_Type_name as:

```
Id  Employee_name  Employee_Salary Code_Type_name
1    empName        20000           abc
```

Im stuck as to how can I write a query for getting such an output.

So far I have a query

```
SELECT employee.id,employee..employee_name,employee..employee_salary,Department.cost  
FROM employee_department
    INNER JOIN employee
        ON employee_department.emp_id = emp.id
    INNER JOIN department 
        ON employee_department.department_id = department.id
    inner join organisation
    on organisation.id =employee.organisation_id
```

where I had used inner join based on common value.Now I need to add this query along with my expected Output

Comment: Join all table to get the result.

Comment: `Select e.* , ct.Code_Type_name
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN Employee_Department  ed ON e.Id = ed.Emp_Id  
INNER JOIN Type tt ON tt.Employee_Department_Id   = ed.Id
INNER JOIN Code c ON c.Id = tt.Code
INNER JOIN CodeType ct ON ct.Id = c.Code_Type_Id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your schema  should be

```
select Id
    , e.Employee_name
    , e.Employee_Salary
    , ct.Code_Type_name
from Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee_Department ed ON ed.Emp_Id = e.id
INNER JOIN Type t.Employee_Department_Id = ed.Department_id
INNER JOIN Code c ON c.id = t.code
INNER JOIN CodeType ct ON ct.id = c.Code_Type_Id
```